# PHP OOP "tail -f" functionality failing

Tags: php

I've recently been working on a PHP "tail -f" type of functionality that prints changes to a file to a web, but can't seem to get it to work due to the following PHP errors:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: tail
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function tailCmd() on a non-object

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
class PHPTail {

    private $logfile = "";
    private $updateTime;
    private $maxSizeToLoad;

    public function __construct($logfile, $defaultUpdateTime = 1000, $maxSizeToLoad = 1048576) {
        $this->log = $logfile;
        $this->updateTime = $defaultUpdateTime;
        $this->maxSizeToLoad = $maxSizeToLoad;
    }

    public function getNewLines($lastFetchedSize, $filters) {
        // some code
    }

    public function tailCmd() {
        // some code
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['var'])) {
    $var = $_GET['var'];
    if(file_exists("logfile-".$var.".txt")) {
        $file = "logfile-".$var.".txt";
    }
    $tail = new PHPTail($file);
}

if(isset($_GET['filters'])) {
    $filters = $_GET['filters'];
}
else {
    $filters = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo $tail->getNewLines($_GET['lastFetchedSizesize'], $filters);
    die();
}

$tail->tailCmd();
?>
```

It seems like the `echo $tail->getNewLines($_GET['lastFetchedSizesize'], $filters);` command seems to be failing when I assign the `$var` variable the value from `$_GET['var'];`, which is a dynamically assigned number from the URL in string format, then I concatenate `$var` into a file location and filename string like so: `$file = "logfile-$var.txt";` or `$file = "logfile-".$var.".txt";`.  That's when I get the above PHP errors, the first of which referring to the `echo $tail->getNewLines` command.

However, everything seems to work fine if I make the `$file` variable equal to a non-concatenated string value like so: `$file = "logfile-1.txt";`.

I'm pretty new to PHP OOP, so I'm guessing that I'm doing something that is illegal, but I so far haven't been able to figure out what that is.  I'm thinking that I have some sort of syntax issue at the `new Class` instantiation `$tail = new PHPTail($file);`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP. You only set `$tail` when `$_GET['var']` is set. If the variable isn't set, you'll get these errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

When `$_GET['var']` isn't set, you never set `$tail`. You need to move all the code that depends on this into the `if` statement.

```
if(isset($_GET['var'])) {
    $var = $_GET['var'];
    if(file_exists("logfile-".$var.".txt")) {
        $file = "logfile-".$var.".txt";
    }
    $tail = new PHPTail($file);

    if(isset($_GET['filters'])) {
        $filters = $_GET['filters'];
    }
    else {
        $filters = "";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
        echo $tail->getNewLines($_GET['lastFetchedSizesize'], $filters);
        die();
    }

    $tail->tailCmd();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When `$_GET['var']` isn't set, your code will never set `$tail`. You need to move all the code that depends on that variable into the if statement.

Try this first
`var_dump $_GET;`